# Appending Digits to end of Int After Converting from Base 95

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to convert a sting from base 95 to an int. For each character in the string I am subtracting by 32 to convert it from base 95 to an int (more details and a conversion table I am using for reference can be found [here](http://www.icerealm.org/FTR/?s=docs&p=base95)). And after converting a character. I want to then append it to the end of an int variable. Here is my code thus far:

```
string name = "!#N$";
int name2;

for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
{
    name2 = name.at(i) - 32;
}
```

I want to append the value of `name2` to the end of the previous value of `name2` so by the end of the loop I have one int. However, I am uncertain of just how to accomplish this. I was considering using the `+=` operator, however that would just add the values up. Likewise I understand that if you `* 10` and then add a digit the digit is appended ([like this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080301210026AA2g7sq)), but I am uncertain of how to implement this solution into my code. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: "If you *10 and then add a digit the digit is appended" - what is there to be uncertain about? Note that in base 95 you presumably want to *95.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I thought he literally wanted to do a bitwise copy of each character into the int. Not thinking at all lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name2 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    int digit = (unsigned char)(name.at(i) - 32); // avoid sign extension
    name2 |= digit << (3 - i) * 8;
}
```

On a side note, what's with all this base 95 business?  I don't really see how it could be useful.  It's not like it's saving any storage space, and it's basically impossible to read.  I also don't know about that conversion function either.  I don't see how a byte-wise subtraction by 32 is going to work.

Comment: Base 95 is just how the data I was given stores the time stamps, no control over that on my end.

Comment: Hmmm... that's interesting.  I guess if for some reason, you had to send a number as text, and wanted to use the least number of characters possible, it could be useful.